# In Kotlin, how to create a single object that has all the features that another class/interface has?

Tags: object, kotlin, inheritance, set, member

I have a `Deck` `object` that has a `Set` member:

```
object Deck {
    val cardSet = mutableSetOf<Card>()
    // other useful functions here...
}
```

Now I can use it in `main()` like this:

```
Deck.cardSet.someFunctionSetHas() // e.g. forEach, map, filter, isEmpty...
```

But would be more intuitive to use it like the following, and that is what I exactly want:

```
Deck.isEmpty()
```

If I try `object Deck: Set<Card> { }`, IDEA asks me to implement some method manually (`contains()`, `containsAll()`, `isEmpty()`, `iterator()`) and `size` member. I want the `Deck` `object` work as a `mutableSet` variable declared like:

```
val mset = mutableSetOf<Card>()
```

In this case I do not need to implement those in-built methods manually. This is the behavior I want for the `Deck` `object`, plus my own declared functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
private val cardSet = mutableSetOf<Card>()
object Deck : MutableSet<Card> by cardSet {
    // other useful functions here...
}
```

Comment: Probably worth adding a link to the [language docs on delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html).

Comment: Does this code work without declaring the cardSet variable itself? Like this:

`object Deck : MutableSet<Card> by mutableSetOf() { // functions... }`

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass an existing MutableSet implementation like HashSet:

```
object Deck: HashSet<Card>() {
    // other useful functions here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html) is probably the best way, as given in another answer.  But for completeness, it might be worth mentioning the [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class, which can be used to create a [dynamic proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html); that's how such things are done in plain Java, and so of course Kotlin/JVM can do it that way too.